# How to customize the filters in the Quickreport saveas dialog?

Tags: delphi, quickreports

In Quickreport, when we click Save button, it will appears many option of extension (QuickReport file(*.qrp), Excel spreadsheet (*.xls), and so on).

I just need to display only QuickReport file as a filter extension option? Is it possible? I read [QuickReport Help](http://ftp.qbss.com/qreport/files/level0/QR4Help.zip) but found nothing.

**Quickreport version 4.06**

Answer (score 0):

Find and delete (or comment out) the `qrextra` and `qrhtml` units in your uses clause, and remove the corresponding componnents (*TQRXLSFilter*, *TQRExcelFilter*,  *TQRHTMLDocumentFilter*, *TQRAsciiExportFilter*, *TQRCommaSeparatedFilter*, *TQRRTFExportFilter*, and *TQRWMFExportFilter*) from any forms in your application. You'll find the full list of all of the available standard export filters in QRExport.pas.

(It's often important to include the version of any third party components you're using, particularly those that change drastically between versions such as QuickReports or Indy, in order to make it easier to answer your question.)

Comment: Quickreport version 4.06. Unfortunately, there is no qrextra and qrhtml units in all my uses clauses and no quickreport filter components in all my forms (_TQRXLSFilter_, _TQRExcelFilter_, _TQRHTMLDocumentFilter_, _TQRAsciiExportFilter_, _TQRCommaSeparatedFilter_, _TQRRTFExportFilter_, and _TQRWMFExportFilter_). But I found **QRExport** unit in my uses clauses

Comment: So look at the QRExport unit, find out what export filters it supports, and search the source code to find out where they're implemented. I've given you the information; it probably wouldn't take much effort to figure out how to use it for your version of QR, especially since the IDE itself supports the Search/Find in files functionality to do the work.

Comment: I found class TQRXLSFilter, and so on inside the QRExport.pas. So I must be to remove it (or comment out) the class declaration? So I need to recreate the QRExport.dcu again after I comment out the declaration of the filters?

Comment: I believe you can just remove the QRExport unit from your project, but I don't have QR 4 to test that belief. You should not have to change the QRExport unit's content. (You know, the QR author has a knowledge base that probably has this information, and if you're a registered user you probably have access to support from them as well.)